# How to create POIs for Wikitude?

Tags: cordova, augmented-reality, wikitude

I want to implement Wikitude World Browser in my PhoneGap app, but I do not know how to create POIs for it. I didn't find any document online.

Does anyone knows how to create POIs for Wikitude?

Answer (score 0):

POIs in Wikitude are created through [ARML](http://openarml.org/wikitude4.html) documents, however I don't know how to integrate them into PhoneGap.